# Run function for multiple values in an array in Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I am running a function that adds the contents of a variable to a URL within the function:

```
var stateWarn = "MA";  //variable to be passed (easy to find and change if I want)

$(window).on('load', function() {
  CheckWarnings();
  setInterval(function(){ CheckWarnings(); }, REFRESH_FREQ);
});

function CheckWarnings() {
  arrayEvents = [];
  console.log("Checking API...");
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/area/' + item,
      jsonp: false,
      type: 'get',
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      cache: true,
      mode: 'no-cors',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data === null) {
          console.log("Data returning with NULL!");
          LoadError();
          return;
        }
        dataTime = data.updated;
        if (!dataTimeCheck) {
          console.log("No check available...creating dataTimeCheck variable 
                      and running jsonCrawler.")
          dataTimeCheck = dataTime;
          console.log("Setting initial datatimeCheck variable to: " + 
          dataTimeCheck);
          jsonCrawler(data);
        } else if (!(dataTime == dataTimeCheck)) {
          console.log("'data' and 'dataTimeCheck' variables do not match... 
          running jsonCrawler.")
          dataTimeCheck = dataTime;
          jsonCrawler(data);
        } else if (dataTime == dataTimeCheck) {
        console.log("No new data detected.")
        return;
      }
      return;
```

I would like to change the variable *stateWarn* to an array:

```
var stateWarn = ["MA", "NH", "NY", "RI"]
```

and run the *CheckWarnings* function for each entry in *stateWarn*. So far, I've had no luck in finding a way to do that with AJAX that works for me. I have done it with Javascript's .forEach command. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What doesn't work for you? What does the rest of your code look like (you've cut it off right when it was getting good; namely, when we say what you were doing with the result of the ajax call).

Comment: I edited my question to include the main function in full. There is more, but this gives enough info, I think.

Comment: Great, that's perfect for the second half of my comment. More important, however, is describing what isn't working. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: As I mentioned below the code, I want to run that function for multiple entries in an array: turn stateWarn = "MA" to statewarn = ["MA", "NH", NY", "RI"] and pass each of those into the function (so I run it 4 times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're dealing here is the difference between *synchronous* and *asynchronous* operations. For this weather api, for getting the Alerts info in a particular geographic `area`, there are generally two formats.

---

**Query String Parameters:**

I'll describe the easier one first, since that will actually allow you do to this with minimal change to your code. Basically, instead of doing `/alerts/active/area/NY`, you pass the area in as a query string parameter. That is, something that looks like: `api.mysite.com/catPics?age=12&breed=sphinx&height=10ft` would mean "access the catPics route with the `age` of 12, the `breed` of sphinx, and the `height` of 10 feet. You can do that here:

```js
const stateWarn = ["MA", "NH", "NY", "RI"];//i'm changing this to a const. better practice!

//for conciseness, I'm also using the $.get function which is a shorthand for your $.ajax({method:get... stuff
$.get('https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?area='+stateWarn.join(','),function(r){
  console.log(r)
});
```

Notice the `stateWarn.join` piece? That means that essentially what we're sending as our request is `https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?area=MA,NH,NY,RI`. Which... works! Note of course that it's probably going to return no real data, since there's not any horrible weather events happening currently in any of those areas.

---

**Multiple Async Requests**
The issue with async it's kinda awkward to do "send request A, then B, then C" for an arbitrary number of requests. So because the `https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/area/STATE` format only accepts ONE argument, you'd essentially have to have each state's request call the next one in line:

```js
const stateWarn = ["MA", "NH", "NY", "RI"];
let i = 0,
  responses = [];

function getNext() {
  $.get('https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/area/' + stateWarn[i], function(r) {
    responses.push(r);
    if (i < stateWarn.length) {
      i++
      getNext()
    }
  })
}
```

But... that's really awkward, and is gonna get nasty if you A) have more than just a few items to go through, or B) if going through that list takes *longer* than your original alert refreshing function. Instead, we'd wanna do something like this.

```js
const alertProms = [],
  stateWarn = ["MA", "NH", "NY", "RI"];
stateWarn.forEach(function(st) {
  proms.push($.get('https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/area/' + st))
})
Promise.all(alertProms).then(function(r) {
  console.log(r)//this would be ALL your requests.
})
```

That's using something called *Promises*. While I won't go into *huge* detail here about them here, Promises basically have three states: Pending, Success, and Failure. There are also a bunch of associated functions with Promises, such as `Promise.all(array)`. This particular function takes an array of HTTP request-like objects (such as the one I made above in `areaProms`) and, when each request gets back, sort of compares the total number of requests sent out to the number of original requests we made.

This is a little more complicated to know, but absolutely essential knowledge once you get into more intricate HTTP/AJAX stuff.

If you wanna know more, I'd really suggest you read MDN's page on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), and specifically the section on Composition.

Comment: HUGE! Thanks for all that info! I didn't realize I could put parameters on the end of that API call...that made this really easy to add with minimal code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should accomplish what you're trying to achieve. You could have it pop the most recent state off the stack every time it runs:

```
var stateWarn = ["MA", "NH", "NY", "RI"],
    dataTimeCheck,
    intervalId;

$(window).on('load', CheckWarnings);

function setupInterval() {
    if (intervalId) {
      return;
    }

    intervalId = setInterval(CheckWarnings, REFRESH_FREQ);
}

function onSuccess(data) {
  if (data === null) {
     console.log("Data returning with NULL!");
     LoadError();
     return;
  }

  dataTime = data.updated;

  if (!dataTimeCheck) {
     console.log("No check available...creating dataTimeCheck variable and running jsonCrawler.");
     dataTimeCheck = dataTime;
     console.log("Setting initial datatimeCheck variable to: " + dataTimeCheck);
     jsonCrawler(data);
  } else if (!(dataTime == dataTimeCheck)) {
     console.log("'data' and 'dataTimeCheck' variables do not match... running jsonCrawler.")
     dataTimeCheck = dataTime;
     jsonCrawler(data);
  } else if (dataTime == dataTimeCheck) {
     console.log("No new data detected.")
  }
}

function CheckWarnings() {
  var curState = stateWarn.pop();

  if (!curState) {
      if (intervalId) {
         window.clearInverval(intervalId);
      }
      return;
  }

  arrayEvents = [];
  console.log("Checking API...");

  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/area/' + curState,
      jsonp: false,
      type: 'get',
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      cache: true,
      mode: 'no-cors',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data) {
         onSuccess(data);

         if (!invervalId) {
            setupInterval();
         }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that requires a whole lot of code changes. It's good to see others' approaches though, so your effort is much appreciated!